# NSDate conversion is messed due to timezone

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents, nsdatepicker

I'm trying to put a time value on a time picker, the problem is that the time gets messed up because of time zone issue. Here's the code snippet I use:

```
 int targetmillisondsFromMidnight = [self.schedule.targetHour intValue]; // 59580000
    NSDate* todayMidnight = [NSCalendar.currentCalendar startOfDayForDate:[NSDate new]]; //2019-12-23 00:00:00 UTC
    NSTimeZone* timezone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    NSInteger seconds = [timezone secondsFromGMT];
    todayMidnight = [todayMidnight dateByAddingTimeInterval:seconds];
    NSDate* scheduleDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:targetmillisondsFromMidnight/1000 sinceDate:todayMidnight]; //2019-12-23 16:33:00 UTC

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:scheduleDate];

    [self.datePicker setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [self.datePicker setDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:components] animated:YES];
```

When I do `po [components hour]` instead of getting 16 as in the `scheduleDate` I get 18.
How can I fix this?
I tried to change the time zones to `localTimeZone` and `timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"` but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do superfluous conversion

Let's consider the following code

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate new]; // << in UTC always

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]]; // << in local 

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:
   (NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date]; // << converted to local
```

debug output:

```
  (lldb) po date
  2019-12-24 09:53:12 +0000

  (lldb) po components
  <NSDateComponents: 0x600003c78710> {
    Hour: 10
    Minute: 53
```